# Server did not respond any content after sending a Get request

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am currently working on REST API, and I am trying to retrive data from my Local Database that is ROBO 3T using API call.

So the problem is that when I sent a Get request to retrive data of all articles using findMany() method of mongoose I got the data, but when I sent a Get request to retrive a specific data using findOne() method of mongoose I didnot get any data from the server but that data is present in database.

here is my code---------------->

```
app.route('/articles/:specificArticleTitle') 
  // req.params.specificArticleTitle ----> gives what the specificArticleTitle passed to the server
  .get((req, res) => {
    Article.findOne({
      title: 'req.params.specificArticleTitle'
    }).then((contentReturned) => {
     
      res.send(contentReturned);

    }).catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
  });
```

ROBO 3T DATABASE --------------->
[image]

Postman --------------------->
[image]
So can somebody help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `req.params.specificArticleTitle`... `findOne({ title: req.params.specificArticleTitle })`

Comment: Do you mean that commented lines?

Comment: No, I mean literally where you have `title: 'req.params.specificArticleTitle'`. It should be `title: req.params.specificArticleTitle`. Not sure why you would think I meant the commented-out line since there aren't any quotes there

Comment: Yes, I got it, it's my bad that I didn't see that one properly. Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score -1):

just remove the quotes around the 'req.params.specificArticleTitle' in title: 'req.params.specificArticleTitle' line.

It should be like this- title: req.params.specificArticleTitle
because its a variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).